# Symfony 2 File Organization

Tags: php, symfony, entities

Recently I began to study SF2 but there are some doubts which I'd like to solve:

Let's say that I have a lot (more than 100) of Models which extend one generic model(Entity). Each model has unique functions (rules for parsing content from model source), what is the best way to organize it?

In ZF1 I would create Model/ModelType/ModelName.php file for every model which need customization, in SF2 I'm not sure what kind of entity should I use: One service container which calls entities and call their custom functions (implemented through interface), or maybe one huge Service which has different functions for every single model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If parsing functions based only on current entity state (use only entity property) it's better to use entity method. Entity aslo can implement some interface, e.g. ParsableInterface.

If paring function need to use another entities it's better to use standalone services handle parsing